# Finding the intersection of UIView While Touch Moving

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

As Shown in the above picture. I have a UIView which will respond our touch events. While I am moving I need to find out Which UIView is below it. For an Example while moving the UIView if it find the UIView which in the above of the picture. We need to find out that It is currently moving across this UIView

Comment: Put your code , what you have done so far. You can find intersects using https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1454747-intersects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the bounds rectangles of each view to a common coordinate system, then see if the rectangles intersect. You can use either view's coordinate system as the common system, in which case you only need to convert one bounds rectangle.

```
extension UIView {
    func intersects(_ her: UIView) -> Bool {
        let herInMyGeometry = convert(her.bounds, from: her)
        return bounds.intersects(herInMyGeometry)
    }
}
```